# Javascript Regex [url=$1]$2[/url] Issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex/javascript code:

```
toReturn = toReturn.replace(/(\[url=)(.+)(\])(.+)(\[\/url\])/g, '<a target=\"_blank\" href="\$2">\$4</a>');
```

But the problem is, if a user inputs:

```
[url=example]example[/url]
some_other_text
[url=example2]example2[/url]
```

It will link the first [url=] with the last [/url] Making just one incorrect url!!!!!

How can I fix this?

Comment: And if the user inputs `[url=javascript:location=http://evil.org]<img onerror="alert(1337)" src="bogus">[/url]` or `[url="><img onerror="alert(1337)" src="bogus]Hello[/url]` then you'll be screwed.

Comment: And how would I stop that Mike Samuel?

Comment: by white-listing URLs by protocol, and properly encoding both the HTML attribute value and the HTML text node using entity escapes.

Comment: to white-list protocols, just make sure that you only match URLs that start with an approved protocol: `(.+?)` -> `((?:http|https|mailto)://.*?)`.  To properly encode the attribute value and text node, replace `'<a target=\"_blank\" href="$2">\$4</a>'` with `function (_, _, url, _, link_text) { return '<a target="blank" href="' + htmlEscape(url) + '">' + htmlEscape(link_text) + '</a>'; }` where `htmlEscape` is `function htmlEscape(s) { return s.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;'); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `(.+?)` instead of `(.+)`, to make the quantifier lazy.